# Dot net 3.5:is appconfig dynamically updated in cache on run time?

Tags: .net, caching, app-config

After application start up ,if i change some value in app.config ,is it reflected in cache object through which i access appconfig properties.

```
    string currentValue = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[currentKey];
```

If it is not so what is possible way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not automatically updated. To force a refresh you could use the [RefreshSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx) method:

```
Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]);
Console.WriteLine("Now modify app.config value");
Console.ReadLine();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]);
```